# How can I connect to Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, go

I am using Fedora 23 and installed `Oracle 12.1` and `Go 1.7.1`

When I run:

```
go get github.com/mattn/go-oci8
```

I am getting an error:

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so when searching for -lclntsh
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
>
> collect2: error: execution of ld completed with return code 1

Comment: The user from you are executing the command is a part of ORACLE group?

Answer (score 1):

What did you put in your oci8.pc file?

I've just got this working with the below.  Keeping in mind I have only the oracle 11.2 instant client installed under the prefix path.  I assume you would have to change the version number to the appropriate number.

```
prefix=/home/sbr/wk/apps/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/sdk/include

glib_genmarshal=glib-genmarshal
gobject_query=gobject-query
glib_mkenums=glib-mkenums

Name: oci8
Description: oci8 library
Libs: -L${libdir} -lclntsh
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Version: 11.2
```

Answer (score 0):

1、install [goracle](https://gopkg.in/goracle.v2)

2、install [TMD GCC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/).

3、use sql.open to connect to Oracle.here is a little Example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "gopkg.in/goracle.v2"
)

func main(){

    db, err := sql.Open("goracle", "scott/tiger@10.0.1.127:1521/orclpdb1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()


    rows,err := db.Query("select sysdate from dual")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error running query")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var thedate string
    for rows.Next() {

        rows.Scan(&thedate)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is: %s\n", thedate)
}
```

from [oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/how-to-connect-a-go-program-to-oracle-database-using-goracle)